# Prevent windows from opening the printing dialog when using java

Tags: java, windows, printing, windows-7

I am trying to make a program that prints a page with several strings, this works just fine but the problem is that it asks me everytime what printer I want to use and this must be transparent for the user (meaning it should print on their default printer without showing the "select device" thingy), so far I've not been able to find a way to do this with java and I don't even know if it is possible, as far as I'm aware you cannot set windows to behave like that either, but I might be mistaken.

By the way, the version is windows 7 if that gives any sort of information at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this in Windows 7, click Start and select the option Devices and Printers. Under Printers and Faxes, right-click the printer you want to make the default, and select Set as default printer. I think this can solve the issue.

Edit : If this doesn't work, make use of print API in java such as :
`import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();`

> Java docs : Locates the default print service for this environment. This may return null. If multiple lookup services each specify a default, the chosen service is not precisely defined, but a platform native service, rather than an installed service, is usually returned as the default. If there is no clearly identifiable platform native default print service, the default is the first to be located in an implementation-dependent manner.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried, but that just opens up the window with the first one displayed beeing the default one.

Comment: Make use of print api in Java such as : import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

Comment: Thanks, I will try it asap and give you some feedback but it looks promising :)